# Using RenderAction() and posting back to sub-controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, renderaction

I have parent view that also renders sub-controller action using `RenderAction()` (that returns a `PartialView`). An example is a front page with Login partial view (inputs: username, password, remember and action: *login*)

### Execution process

1. GET for `Home/Index` - also displays my login control that has its *login* pointing to sub controller `User/Login`
2. User enters credentials and clicks *login*
3. POST for `User/Login` - checks credentials and returns **???**

### Problem

**How do I return back to parent view from my sub controller action `User/Login`?**
My sub controller's partial view can be rendered any page, so I can't just easily return result of parent controller action like:

```
return new HomeController().Index();
```

So how should I process my sub controller action and its partial view?

### EDIT

I could post back to my sub-controller action with additional data of the parent route, but I also populate data in my sub-controller action. In my example I have to display that someone's credential weren't valid. A redirect would lose these...

Comment: Just a thought is it possible to implement a AJAX postback instead on the login control? This way you wont need to leave the page.

Comment: It is possible, but the whole solution supports non-javascript processing as well. That's why it's a problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of posting to /User/Login for performing the login, append a return url, so you would end up with /User/Login?returnUrl=/Home/Index (url encoding might change that a bit)

If returnUrl is set in the querystring, the action for /User/Login should just return a redirect action back to that returnUrl.

Sorry if that was a little unclear

Comment: It is clear. But let me add some *EDIT* to my question. the thing is if I populate ie. ModelState.Errors they will get lost on redirect, won't they?

Comment: Most sites do this by having a dedicated login page that displays errors if the credentials are invalid. If the authentication is successfull, the user is redirected to the returnUrl (or the defaultUrl if returnUrl doesn't exist). If the authentication fails, the user stays on /User/Login. /User/Login contains a login form and an area to display the errors...